# jQuery filter elements and add class if class not present and if it's the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to filter through a set of elements, adding the class 'active' to the first element only if another element in the set does not contain the class 'active'.

I'd also like to hide the other elements if the above statement is true.

**Existing code that needs editing**

```
$mmenu.not(':eq(0)').hide();
$mmenu.eq(0).addClass('active');
$mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');
```

**My current failed attempt**

```
$mmenu.filter(function( index ) {

    console.log(index);

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $mmenu.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');
    };

    $(this).not('.active').hide();
});
```

**Codepen**

[Pen](http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/snqgA/) - (edit: now shows correct working example)

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle that includes some of the markup so that we know what we're acting on?

Comment: @JayBlanchard hopefully this helps - http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/snqgA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want..

```
// check and store if .active element exists
var active = $mmenu.not(':first').is('.active');

// if it doesn't exists
if (!active){
    $mmenu.hide() // hide all
          .removeClass('active') // remove the active class from any that have it
          .first() // select the first only
          .addClass('active') // give it the active class
          .show(); // and show it 
}
```

Comment: So simple, so effective... thank you! I've posted the full code for the menu system below, I know this is going above and beyond, but any input on how to refactor that would be amazing... it feels clunky!

Comment: @sam, you might want to post that over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and tag it for refactoring. It is a dedicated stackexchange site just for this reason..

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47220/refactoring-advice-for-responsive-jquery-restaurant-menu-system

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Gaby aka G.Petrioli , the working code is as follows:

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {

            var $mmenu = $('.menu__main');

            if ($mmenu.length > 0) {

                var $mnav = $('.menu__nav'),
                    $mnav_a = $mnav.find('a'),
                    m = parseInt($mnav.outerHeight(true), 10),
                    $contain = $mmenu.closest('.menu-container'),
                    h = 0,
                    l = 0;

                // check and store if .active element exists
                var active = $mmenu.not(':first').is('.active');

                // if it doesn't exists
                if (!active) {
                    $mmenu.hide() // hide all
                        .removeClass('active') // remove the active class from any that have it
                        .first() // select the first only
                        .addClass('active') // give it the active class
                        .show(); // and show it 

                    $mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');

                $mmenu.each(function(z) {

                    var $this = $(this);

                    $this.css('height','auto');

                    $this.css({
                        zIndex: z+1,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: m + "px",
                        left: l,
                        height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
                    });

                    l = l - $this.outerWidth();

                });

                $contain.height($mmenu.eq(0).height());

            } else {

                $mmenu.each(function(z) {

                    var $this = $(this);

                    $this.css('height','auto');

                    $this.css({
                        zIndex: z+1,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: m + "px",
                        height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
                    });

                });

                var $new_contain = $('.menu__main.active').height();

                $contain.height($new_contain);

            }

                $mnav_a.on('click', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this = $(this);

                    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {

                        $mmenu.stop(true, true);

                        $mnav_a.removeClass('active');
                        $this.addClass('active');

                        $mmenu.filter($('.active'))
                            .removeClass('active')
                            .fadeOut(250)
                            .animate({left:l+"px"}, 250);

                        var $target = $mmenu.filter($this.attr('href'));

                        $contain.animate({height:$target.height()}, 250);

                        $target.addClass('active')
                            .fadeIn(250)
                            .animate({left:0}, 250);
                    }

                    $this.blur();
                });
            }
        });
```